# How to find coordinates of an element relative to browser window

Tags: javascript

I want coordinates of an element relative to the browser window. So if an element is at top-left corner of browser can I get it's coordinates as x=0, y=0. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) script or use jquery [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: jQuery's `offset` is relative to the document, not the browser window.

Comment: So it the referenced script.